# Crear una vista desde cero

Tags: html, html5, asp.net-mvc

Estoy trabajando con ASP.NET MVC, estoy creando mis vistas desde cero a puro html, al crear una vista vacía me crea esto.

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Proveedor";
}

<h2>Proveedor</h2>
```

Pero al crear código html hago esto

```
   @{
    ViewBag.Title = "Proveedor";
}

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Proveedor</h2>

</body>
</html>
```

Quisiera saber si la parte del ViewBag va por fuera del html o va por dentro y si va por dentro en que parte va?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El `ViewBag` es una variable global, si en tu vista parcial `_LayoutView` tienes algo como esto:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    @RenderBody()

</body>
</html>
```

tu código es correcto y en cada pagina que cargues tus `<title>` serán modificados por donde lo mejor seria eliminar las etiquetas `<title>` de tu vista esto es solo una linea de mas que no sera necesaria.

Si no tienes definida un `_LayoutView` lo mejor sera eliminar

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Proveedor";
}
```

y dejar

```
<title>Proveedor</title>
```

ó si prefieres dejarlo

```
<title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
```

Por lo tanto respondiendo a tu pregunta:
**¿Quisiera saber si la parte del `ViewBag` va por fuera del `html` o va por dentro y si va por dentro en que parte va?**

No importa la posición donde lo pongas, pero lo recomendable es dejarlo al principio ya que se puede identificar que vista estas modificando, como mencione anteriormente si no usas un `_LayoutView`

Comment: muy buena respuesta hermano! :D

Comment: Se me olvido mencionar lo que dice @Flxtr *El ViewBag solo se podrá utilizar como interacción directa entre el Controller y el View*

Comment: En mi carpeta Shared solo tengo _Layout.cshtml, no estoy usando vistas parciales hasta ahora, por otro lado que pasa si borro esa parte del ViewBag voy a tener usar puro codigo cliente ya sea con jquery y el $.ajax para invocar un action del controler que retorne el json que usare para cargar controles

Comment: No pasa nada si lo borras, solo es código por default

Answer (score 4):

El `ViewBag` puede ir en cualquier parte de tu archivo `.cshtml`, a excepción de los `@section` y básicamente se define como un objeto dinámico que sirve de interacción entre el `Controller` y el `View` para el paso de información *temporal* del uno al otro.

Es importante mencionar que el `ViewBag` solo se podrá utilizar como interacción directa entre el `Controller` y el `View`, y éste se va a ir `reciclando` entre futuras interacciones.

Del lado del `Controller`, el uso y asignación es:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ViewBag.MyMessageToUsers = "Hello from me.";
    ViewBag.AnswerText = "Your answer goes here.";
    return View();
}
```

Ahora, para leerlo del lado del `View` directamente en una tabla de HTML (a modo de ejemplo):

```
<tr>
    <td>MyMessageToUsers: @ViewBag.MyMessageToUsers </td>
</tr>
```

Referencias: [Página](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controllerbase.viewbag(v=vs.118).aspx) de la documentación oficial.